# How do I pass two build parameters to bundle config?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm trying to configure bundler such that building the mysql2 gem will pass the necessary parameters to extconf. Problem is, I can't figure out how to pass more than one parameter.

In my Gemfile, I just have:

```
gem mysql2, '= 0.3.11'
```

(There is some problem with the latest version which prevents compiling it at all, so I'm using 0.3.11 based on a recommendation I found on another post somewhere around here.)

I tried this:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-include=C:\DevEnv\Tools\Ruby\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\include --with-mysql-lib=C:\DevEnv\Tools\Ruby\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\lib
```

I also tried quoting the parameters into a single parameter:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 "--with-mysql-include=C:\DevEnv\Tools\Ruby\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\include --with-mysql-lib=C:\DevEnv\Tools\Ruby\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\lib"
```

I can tell it isn't working because gem is showing me the command-line which is actually being used, and then the build fails because it can't provide the lib):

```
C:/DevEnv/Tools/Ruby/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-include=C:\DevEnv\Tools\Ruby\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\include
```

If I provide just the `--with-mysql-lib` parameter or swap the order of the parameters, the build passes on looking for the lib but fails on a missing include instead.

If I pass the same flags to gem directly, that works fine. But that won't be terribly great when it comes time to deploy.

How are other people doing this?

PS a binary DLL would have been nice, but I guess they stopped doing that.

Answer (score 1):

For the next poor sap that has to deal with this, the answer is a lot of quoting:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 "--with-mysql-include=\"C:\DevEnv\Tools\Ruby\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\include\" --with-mysql-lib=\"C:\DevEnv\Tools\Ruby\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\lib\""
```

Comment: This is probably right. I wonder if it's OK to accept the answer - I can no longer verify it, on account of no longer using Windows for development (because of this sort of silliness!)

Comment: Heh, I'm using the same formatting for passing in compile flags on Linux https://github.com/poise/poise/blob/master/.travis.yml#L22-L24

Comment: Yeah, on Linux and OSX, it's definitely correct and it's normal to escape with a backslash here. On Windows, backslash is not the usual escape character, because they just have to do everything differently from the norm.

Answer (score -1):

```
bundle config --local --with-mysql-include 'C:\INC_PATH\include'
bundle config --local --with-mysql-lib 'C:\LIB_PATH\lib'
```

The above will store configuration directives in current directory in `.bundle/config` file. After you have these two directives run, try normal `build install`. Hope it helps.

[More info](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_config.html).

Comment: No good. The second one overwrites the first, so I can only have one or the other set at the same time. I wish their docs would explicitly say how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Oh, I accidentally made a typo in the answer. There was a weird `=` sign in the second line, so sorry. Now I fixed an answer with proper lines.